# How to create a simple pop-up div that loads an external page from an onclick event?

Tags: jquery, html, parameters, onclick, popup

Since I'm very new to jQuery I'm having some troubles with this issue. I'm having persons displayed in a table. When I click on one person I want a simple pop-up with some more information about that person. I can find example how to make a div pop-up from a click event, but not how to parse the id into the page that loads. And how to close the div if I click somewhere outside.

I'm also looking for an option to clear the div when leaving it, so if you click another id, you wont see the old one until it is loaded.

I found this example which suits my needs if I can get the pop-up to behave properly. Look at the demo [here.](http://hjalmarson.net/divtest/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Tutorial - Pop-up div on hover</title>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #000 url(bg-texture.png) repeat;
    color: #dddddd;
  }

  h1, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  a {
    color: #EB067B;
  }

  div#container {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  }

  /* HOVER STYLES */
  div#pop-up {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 90%;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;

    $('a#trigger').click(function(e) {
  $('#pop-up').load('page.php?id=$id');
      $('#pop-up').show();
  $("#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
      //.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
      //.css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
      //.appendTo('body');
    }, function() {
      $('div#pop-up').hide();
    });


  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <h1>jQuery Tutorial - Pop-up div on hover</h1>
  <p>
    To show hidden div, simply hover your mouse over
    <a href="#" id="trigger" value="999">this link</a>.
  </p>

  <!-- HIDDEN / POP-UP DIV -->
  <div id="pop-up">pop-up</div>
  <br />

what im trying to do<br>
onclick - show div, and load name.php?id=999 into the div<br>
keep the div open until one click outside the div, or if there is a exit button inside div.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the file I created to include in the div:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo "You have clicked on id: $id";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. Clicking on the link below, will open the pop-up and add the parameter 332 to the url.

```
<a href="#" id="332">this link has id 332, but is just an example</a>.


$("body").click(function(e) {

    $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false 
    }); 

    //get the value from the clicked DIV
    var idName = e.target.id;

    //pass the id from the div to the URL by adding idName
    var urlToLoad = 'page.php?groupId=' + idName

    //load the url with the passed parameter
    $('#popUp').load(urlToLoad);
    $('#popUp').show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the id is on this line:

$('#pop-up').load('page.php?id=$id');

Change it to:

$('#pop-up').load("page.php?id="+id);

And then set your ID variable somewhere.

To get it to be clean the next time, I'd just empty the contents of the div when you hide it.

Not sure about closing it off the top of my head.

Comment: I can't get it to work, and I think I mislead you a little bit. I want to pass the value in the div, not the div id itself to the url. How can I do that?

Comment: In the anonymous click function, you need to make a variable named id and set it equal to 999 (or whatever the ID of the user you want info on is; it'll have to be more complicated in the real page). Then, the "page.php?id="+id will become "page.php?id=999", and it'll pop up the right page.